# large flow diagram adjustment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw a flow diagram in latex and the mini-chart is bigger the rectangle. How can I adjust the outside rectangle to fit everything inside it. Is it also possible to rotate text in the diagram. My code so far.[image: flow diagram]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
  \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=2.0cm,y=2.0cm]
            \clip(-0.99,-0.98) rectangle (17.6,7.6);
            \draw (3,1.5)-- (4.5,1.5); %stom top
            \draw (2.5,2.5)-- (2.5,2); %left side liver
            \draw (2.5,2.5)-- (5,2.5); %Liver top
            \draw (5,2.5)-- (5,2); %right side liver
            \draw (5,2)-- (2.5,2); %liver bottom
            \draw (3,1.5)-- (3,0.5); %stom side left
            \draw (4.5,1.5)-- (4.5,0.5); %stom side right
            \draw (4.5,0.5)-- (3,0.5); % stom bottom
            \draw [->] (2.71,1.26) -- (3.05,1.26); %stomuch to gut
            \draw (2.71,1.26)-- (2.71,2); %liver to gut
            \draw (4.5,1.22)-- (4.8,1.22); %gut to liver
            \draw [->] (4.81,1.22) -- (4.81,2);
            \draw (3,3.5)-- (3,3); %spleen side left
            \draw (3,3.5)-- (4.5,3.5); % spleen top
            \draw (4.5,3.5)-- (4.5,3); % spleen side right
            \draw (3,3)-- (4.5,3); % spleen bottom
            \draw (4.5,3.28)-- (4.76,3.28); %spleen to liver
            \draw [->] (4.77,3.28) -- (4.77,2.5);
            \draw (2.5,4.5)-- (2.5,4); %muscle left side
            %   \draw (2.5,4)-- (2.5,4.5);
            \draw (2.5,4.5)-- (5,4.5); %muscle top
            \draw (5,4.5)-- (5,4); %muscle right side
            \draw (5,4)-- (2.5,4); % muscle bottom
            \draw (2.5,-0.5)-- (2.5,0); %bone left side
            \draw (2.5,0)-- (5,0); %bone top
            \draw (5,0)-- (5,-0.5); %bone right side
            \draw (2.5,-0.5)-- (5.0,-0.5); %bone bottom
            %%%
            \draw (2.5,-0.85)-- (5.0,-0.85); %kidney bottom
            \draw (2.5,-0.98)-- (5.5,-0.95); %bone top
            %\draw (5,0)-- (5,-0.5); %bone right side
            %\draw (2.5,-0.5)-- (5.0,-0.5); %bone bottom

            \draw(2.5,5.5)--(5,5.5); %fat top
            \draw(5.0,5.5) --(5,5.0); % fat right side
            \draw(2.5, 5.5) --(2.5,5.0); % fat left side
            \draw(2.5,5.0)--(5.0,5.0); % fat bottom
            \draw(2.5,6.0)--(5.0,6.0); % brain bottom
            \draw(5.0,6.5)--(5.0,6.0); % brain right side
            \draw(2.5,6.0)--(2.5,6.5); % brain left side
            \draw(2.5,6.5)--(5.0,6.5); % brain bottom
            \draw (1,15.5)-- (1,-7.5); %side
            \draw (1,-0.98)-- (1.5,-0.98); %bottom
            \draw (1.5,-13.5)-- (1.5,13.5);
            \draw (1.5,17.3)-- (1.5,17.3); %top
            \draw (6,13.5)-- (6,-9.5); %side left
            \draw (6,-0.98)-- (6.5,-0.98);
            \draw (6.5,-15.5)-- (6.5,15.5); %side bottom
            \draw (6,16.5)-- (6.5,16.5); rectabgle top
            \draw (-0.5,1)-- (0.5,1); %stomu
            \draw (0.5,1)-- (0.5,0.5);
            \draw (0.5,0.5)-- (-0.5,0.5);
            \draw (-0.5,0.5)-- (-0.5,1); stomu
            \draw [->] (0.5,0.76) -- (2.94,0.76);
            \draw [->] (4.5,0.86) -- (7.07,0.86);
            \draw [->] (0,1.5) -- (0,1);
            \draw (0.65,2.07) node[anchor=north west] {\textbf{Artertial blood}};
            \draw (3.51,4.31) node[anchor=north west] {muscle};
            \draw (3.49,3.31) node[anchor=north west] {Spleen};
            \draw (3.56,2.39) node[anchor=north west] {Liver};
            \draw (3.65,1.05) node[anchor=north west] {Gut};
            \draw (3.57,-0.17) node[anchor=north west] {Bone};
            \draw (-0.18,0.8) node[anchor=north west] {Stomach};
            \draw (-0.14,1.76) node[anchor=north west] {Dose};
            \draw (7.12,0.94) node[anchor=north west] {elimination};
            \draw (5.81,3.16) node[anchor=north west] {\textbf{Venous blood}};
            \draw [->] (5,2.23) -- (6,2.23);
            \draw [->] (5,4.3) -- (6,4.3);
            \draw [->] (1.5,4.24) -- (2.5,4.24);
            \draw [->] (5.0,-0.30) -- (6,-0.30);
            \draw [->] (1.5,-0.24) -- (2.5,-0.24);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want your code to generate a diagram in the image? Where is/should be "mini chart"? Where is outside rectangle? Around all diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so far I was able reconstruct from your code (with considering visible part of showed image of diagram) the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}% {article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
   \pgfsetlayers{background,%
                 main,%
                 foreground%
                 }

  \begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}[ht]
%        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = {Triangle[angle=60:2pt 3]},
node distance = 1mm and 11mm,
  start chain = A going below,
box/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, fill=gray!30,
              minimum height=5mm, minimum width=#1,
              on chain=A},
box/.default = 16mm,
mpn/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, fill=gray!30,
              rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
              rectangle split draw splits=false,
              minimum width=9mm,
              on chain=A,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
              \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
              \draw[dashed, thin]
              (\LN.one split west) -- (\LN.one split east);
              \end{pgfonlayer}
                            }}
              },
jump/.pic = {\draw[line cap=rect]  (.06,0)  coordinate (-out)
                          arc (0:180:0.06)  coordinate (-in);
             },
                ]
\node[box] {Lung};          % A-1
\node[box] {Brain};
\node[box] {Fat};
\node[box] {Muscle};
\node[box=9mm] {Spleen};
\node[box] {Liver};
\node[mpn] {Gut\nodepart{two}}; % A-7
\node[box] {Bone};
\node[box] {Kidney};
\node[box] {Skin};
\node[box] {Heart};
\node[box] {Carcas};            % A-12
%
\node[align=center, font=\bfseries,
      left =of A-5]  {Arterial\\ Blood};
\node[align=center, font=\bfseries,
      right=of A-5]  {Venous\\ Blood};
% stomach-gut-liver
\node[box, left=of A-7.one west] {Stomach};   % A-13
\node (A-14) [align=center,left=of A-13] {Oral\\ dosing};
    \draw[->]   (A-14) -- (A-13);
    \draw[->]   ([xshift=1mm] A-6.south west) coordinate (jmp1) % NEW
                               |- (A-7.two west);
    \draw[->]   (A-7.one east) -| ([xshift=-1mm] A-6.south east);
% spleen -- liver
\draw[->]   (A-5) -| ([xshift=-1mm] A-6.north east);
% left connecting lines
\draw[->]   (A-1.west) -- ++ (-.5,0) coordinate (aux-1)
                           |- (A-12);
\foreach \i in {2,...,6,8,9,...,12}
\draw[->]   (aux-1 |- A-\i) -- (A-\i);
% input line with jumps over lines NEW
\path (aux-1 |- A-7.one west) pic (jmp2) {jump};
\path (jmp1  |- A-7.one west) pic (jmp3) {jump};
% from kidney -- to east
\draw[->]   (A-13) -- (jmp2-in)
            (jmp2-out) -- (jmp3-in)
            (jmp3-out) -- (A-7.one west);
% right connecting lines
\draw       (A-12.east) -- ++ (.5,0) coordinate (aux-2)
                       |- (A-1);
\foreach \i in {2,...,4,6,9,10,11}
\draw[->]   (A-\i) -- (aux-2 |- A-\i);
% output lines with jumps over lines NEW
% from Gut
\path (aux-2 |- A-7.two east) pic (jmp4) {jump}; 
\draw[->]   (A-7.two east) -- (jmp4-in) 
            (jmp4-out) -- ++ (1.5,0);
% from kidney -- to east
\path ([yshift=-1.5mm] aux-2 |- A.east) pic (jmp5) {jump};;
\draw[->]   ([yshift=-1.5mm] A-9.east) -- (jmp5-in)
            (jmp5-out) -- ++ (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    `\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** added are missing output lines and locus at lines cross points

Comment: @marmot, thank you very much. I must confess that was lost in OP code, so at reconstructing showed (part) of image I overlooked this line. I still have problem with understanding, what OP like to have.

Comment: I was trying to represent the different blocks inside a rectangle on my code because I thought it was easier than the line. Thank you, it looks perfect @Zarko

Comment: I would like to add another arrow from the kidney exiting the system (like the gut arrow). I tried \draw[->]   (A-9.one east) -- ++ (1.5,0); but it looks like it from the venous blood exiting system  @Zarko

Comment: @SneMtshali, what happens that you cancel acceptance of my answer?

Comment: I was probably scrolling on the screen and clicked by mistake @Zarko